# About lying as self defense and saving a life

Tags: halal-haram, lying

is telling lies permissible for self defense if youre at the mercy of a robber to save yourself?
Ive been kidnapped and still i spoke the truth.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in such a situation it would be permissible to lie. Allah says in the Quran:

“He who disbelieves in Allah after his having believed, not he who is compelled while his heart is at rest on account of faith, but he who opens (his) breast to disbelief-- on these is the wrath of Allah, and they shall have a grievous chastisement.”

This verse explains that if a Muslim feels his life is at risk, and pretends not to be a Muslim to save his life - he has been compelled-  then such a person is forgiven and will not be held accountable.

However, it is also permissible to stand your ground and speak the truth regardless. In the story of ashaabul Kahf, the 7 sleepers in the cave could have just falsely pretended to have disbelieved in Allah and claimed to worship idols, but instead, they left their city and refused to worship idols.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's permissible in some conditions.

Asma bint Yazid narrated that the Messenger of Allah said:

> "it is not lawful to lie except in three cases: Something the man tells his wife to please her, to lie during war, and to lie in order to bring peace between the people."

Some scholars say that the lie can be in the form of allusion/confusion/hiding in three situations above.

Also, lying is permitted in those conditions:

- When your or another muslim's life is under serious threat,
- When your goods/values are under serious threat
- When you have to keep secret of a muslim
- When you have to keep shame of a muslim secret